# Summation identity involving logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, logarithms

I'm having trouble understanding why this identity holds:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{(\log n) - 1} \frac{n}{\log (n - k)}  + \theta(1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\log n} \frac{n}{k}+ \theta(1) $$

Any pointers to a proof would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are there some floor functions involved?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $$\sum_{k=0}^{\log(n) - 1} \frac{n}{\log(n) - k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\log(n)} \frac{n}{k}$$ In any case, how are you defining a sum with a non-integer limit?

Comment: @the-chaz I think you're right. This is related to proving bounds for functions. I've seen the equation in a couple of different places, but I'm getting the feeling that it's not a strict equality but a short-hand.

Comment: @robjohn No this is the form I've seen the equation in. What I left out of the equation is that there is also a constant factor on each side. updating post to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

The equation is not true in the form given.
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\log(n) - 1} \frac{n}{\log(n)}\\
&\le\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\log(n) - 1} \frac{n}{\log(n - k)}\\
&\le\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\log(n) - 1} \frac{n}{\log(n-\log(n))}\\
&=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n-\log(n))}\\
&\to1
\end{align}
$$
However,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\log(n)} \frac{n}{k}
&=\log(\log(n))+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{\log(n)}\right)\\
&\to\infty
\end{align}
$$
**On the other hand:**

If the equation was as I suggested in my comment above:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\log(n) - 1} \frac{n}{\log(n) - k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\log(n)} \frac{n}{k}
$$
and the upper limits should be treated as a bound for the sum in $k$, not as an actual value to be used, essentially applying $\operatorname{floor}$ to the upper limits, as The Chaz suggested, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor} \frac{n}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor - 1} \frac{n}{\log(n) - k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor} \frac{n}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor} \frac{n}{\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor + k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\frac{n(\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor)}{k(\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor + k)}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Since $0\le\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor<1$
$$
\begin{array}{}
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\le\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\frac{1}{k(\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor + k)}\le\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\frac{1}{k^2}\tag{2}
\end{array}
$$
Thus, $(1)$ is between
$$
n(\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor)\left(1-\frac{1}{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor+1}\right)
$$
and
$$
n(\log(n) - \lfloor\log(n)\rfloor)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor+1}\right)
$$
So this doesn't match your statement, either, since the difference is $O(n)$.

Comment: Of course, treating the given upper limits "... as a bound for the sum in $k$, not as an actual value to be used" is a perfectly reasonable interpretation/assumption, but it definitely should have been stated in the OP! (+1) for a thorough clearing-up of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It would also be a good idea to address the questions brought up in comments so far, proper inclusion of floors and parentheses would be very important to this problem and its solution.

I believe that the best way to approach a proof of this equality would be to examine the forms of each element in the sum individually. Looking at what you have posted, I can see that the first and last elements of each sum are equivalent:
$$
(k = 0) n/log(n-0) = n/log(n)
$$
$$
(k = log(n)) n/k = n/log(n)
$$
It seems to me that the same is true for the last & first elements as well. Perhaps this can be proved by showing that these sums are equivalent in general, though in reverse order as given. If that doesn't work, I would try a proof by induction.